# SSIS call web service

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm

I working with SSIS and Microsoft Dynamic CRM
then I Migrate a million record data to CRM using CRMSDK

My code in web service using Multi-threading for better performance but I think It's hard to tracking and control.

So. I have some question Please see this image below
[image]

Data Flow my SSIS

1. I Query my data in Staging with rank like this

   SELECT *,RANK() OVER (.....) FROM StgTable WHERE status = 'Ready'
2. Then I Control Flow with Rank Number For Example 
   IF Rank Number = 1 Then Call Web Service 1
                  = 2 Then Call Web service 2

So... My Question is If I use this SSIS when Execute my All Web service Run at same time Or not ?

(My Target is I want to run more than 1 row at same time)

Thank you.

Comment: it might worth to take a look: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 4 calls will be executed the same time.